# Isolate computer from network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, piracy

My roommate and I use the same network. Problem is he has no respect to security he originally wanted to have the network unlocked but after a long time I convinced him to lock it.

But now he doesnt even care about his computer he has no antivirus no firewall and uses pirated OS and programs. I am using ubuntu and I have hundreds of euros worth of work saved on my computer and I am worried for an attacker on his computer can gain access to mine.
I looked into my router configuration there is a "Isolate wireless" button but no description or anything does that close multicast or what.

Is there a way to isolate his computer to the rest of the network? Or is there a way I can convince him that using pirated OS/software is bad for his computer and the network overall?

I am using a netfaster IAD router and has most advanced features(except VLAN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most routers have the option to isolate systems. Clearly your one does. Just click the button.

For a brief rundown of Wireless Isolation you can read up [here](http://www.wirelessisolation.com/)

The issue you likely have here is, depending on the security of your friends system, a security concern could gain access to your network through other means regardless of isolation.

I would suggest you enforce some security with your roommate if you don't want to have any serious problems.

Comment: What do you mean other means? if the 2 computers are completely isolated from communicating how can one impact the other

Comment: You can isolate a system to prevent one system talking to another (as you would in a hotspot for example), but bother are still connected to the same network. For most security threats this will be all you need, but in the event of a hack going from a system A to network to system B is not much of a stretch. Granted it's highly unlikely, but it depends how concerned you are.

Comment: Also is isolation any different from: Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing) on the firewall as I have already done?

Comment: If it's the firewall on your router then no it is not the same as the rules apply to internal/external to the network rather than specific systems internally. The firewall on your personal computer then that should also get the job done, but might hinder your general internet use.

Comment: Its my systems firewall (ubuntu) and I havent seen any restrictions on my usage what I use works fine as I dont run any servers etc.

Comment: Then you can run that if you so wish. Provided you have a robust firewall setup. Although you are using Ubuntu, so you should be set ;)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to block his ip address for your computer, but then you will not be able to exchange files. you can also block specific ports, and leave some open for an ip address

Comment: the ip is not static the ips are pulled of routers dhcp server so at a restart I might end up blocking my phone or myself

Comment: you can map static ip address to your roommate's computer's physical mac address in your router to solve this issue

Comment: You can also set your roommate's computer specify an IP address in the network settings if he doesn't take the computer out of your network.

Comment: This should be a simple way to at least stop data coming from his computer to yours to at least stop an attack from his computer.